# MySQL exact match not working on 17-digit CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I have an unusual duplicate issue in a query I'm running in MySQL.

```
SELECT pg.filename,
       pg.taken, 
       pg.event as event_id, 
       pg.id, 
       CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pg.taken), LPAD(pg.id, 7, 0)) as uniq 
       from photogallery pg 
       WHERE CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pg.taken), LPAD(pg.id, 7, 0)) = 15074515800000516
```

This query should return only one row (since the CONCAT and LPAD function is combining the form of date and ID, the primary key.

However it is returning three rows. It doesn't return three rows for every combination of CONCAT and LPAD, though.

I don't seem to have the issue if I reduce the LPAD to 6.

The CONCAT / LPAD function results in a 17-digit number, but what I've read online doesn't seem to suggest this should be an issue leading to duplicates in my result?

I get that the date is the same, but the ID is not, so the number is still unique...?

Example dataset:

```
filename      taken                event_id    id
1973-213.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        515
1973-214.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        516
1973-215.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        517
```

Result I'm getting (not correct, should be getting only row with ID of 516...)

```
filename      taken                event_id    id     uniq
1973-213.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        515    15074515800000515
1973-214.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        516    15074515800000516
1973-215.jpg  2017-10-08 08:33:00  1973        517    15074515800000517
```

EDIT: Could this in any way be down to the fact that my table structure has id set up as int(11)?

Comment: Your compare in WHERE has numeric context. Test `WHERE CONCAT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pg.taken), LPAD(pg.id, 7, 0)) = '15074515800000516'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Akina has right. You compare numbers. And because 17-digits number is tu big for standard signed `INT`, which can hold max `2147483647`, numbers are casting to `DOUBLE`. Standard `DOUBLE` has 15-digits precision, so 17-digits numbers are rounded.

OK, now You ask if `DOUBLE` has 15-digits precision, why my 16-digits numbers are not rounded? In fact `DOUBLE` has exact 53 binary digits precision, what means 15.95 decimal digits, so rounding of 16 digits numbers occurs very rarely.

More on type casting in MySQL Manual: [12.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html)

More on floating points numbers like `DOUBLE` in Wikipedia: [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)